# Split a List into Separate Lists [Python]

Tags: python, list

I have a list, say

```
listx = [1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 0, 4]
```

How do you split the list into consecutive parts not containing 0s? For example, this list would be split into

```
separated = [[1, 2], [5, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6], [4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

In [69]: L = [1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 0, 4]

In [70]: [list(i[1]) for i in itertools.groupby(L, bool) if i[0]]
Out[70]: [[1, 2], [5, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6], [4]]
```

Comment: Hey, both you and I answered this one already. :-)

Comment: @DSM: really? /me runs and checks history

Comment: Couldn't you just use `bool` instead of `lambda x:x!=0` ?

Comment: @khelwood: good point. Just updated.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: yep, the dup I linked has solutions from both you and me.  I remembered at once 'cause I was fond of a certain turn of phrase..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's a good thing your solution is faster since this is a *huge* input dataset and we know this is the bottleneck of the code.

Comment: @SethMMorton, I have seen people recommend reducing the number of assignment operations to boost performance, I would like to hear what you would have to say about that, just because something is done with itertools does not mean it is better or in fact more readable.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham And just because something is more efficient does not make it better.  I would say the same thing to the assignment people.

Comment: @SethMMorton, well I suppose it is up to the OP to decide whether it matters or not, your input is the least relevant detail of the whole thread.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I admit my first comment was rather childish and immature. I responded that way because I have always thought it to be rather bad taste to make a comment on someone else's answer to state your answer is better. Next time I'll make sure I just say what I mean rather than use heavy sarcasm.

Comment: @SethMMorton, It was not about having a better answer, I added the comment because when itertools is involved in an answer a lot of people automatically presume that it must be more efficient than a loop, when I originally timed both functions DSM pointed out that my code was adding empty lists for consecutive 0's and presumed I imagine that was the reason the loop was more efficient but I used filter to handle the case and it was still more efficient which will be surprising no doubt to some people.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no repeating `0's`:

```
listx = [1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 0, 4]

final = [[]]
for ele in listx:
    final[-1].append(ele) if ele else final.append([])

print(final)
[[1, 2], [5, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6], [4]]
```

If you have repeating `0's`:

```
def split_l(l):
    final = [[]]
    for ele in l:
        final[-1].append(ele) if ele else final.append([])
    return filter(None, final)

In [146]: timeit split_l(L)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.6 ms per loop

In [147]: timeit  [list(i[1]) for i in itertools.groupby(L, bool) if i[0]]
10 loops, best of 3: 33.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Your version and the other don't do the same thing in case of repeated zeros (you generate empty lists).  Since the OP didn't specify either approach makes sense, although I think the no-list output looks cleaner.

Comment: @DSM, handled the case where 0's are repeated, still more efficient

Comment: Yep, the zeroes would need to be pretty sparse before groupby would start winning performance-wise.  That's one downside of itertools-based approaches, they're not always as fast as one could want.  On the bright side, they're pretty.

Comment: @DSM, indeed, groupby seems to be one that falls into that category the most, for me at least.